# how to convert different number systems to base ten in the simplest way

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have searched for this question on the website but do not understand most of the solutions posted.
 my question is;
i have a method:

```
public static int convertToDecimal(int number, int base)
```

it will receive a number and base, then multiply them thus:

```
(1023, 4) passed to the method will be (1 * Math.pow(4,3)) + (0* Math.pow(4,2))+(2* Math.pow(4,1))+(3* Math.pow(4,0)) will return 75.
```

please I am very new to java and do not yet understand the sophisticated methods of doing this. the goal is to understand how to do the iriteration. thanks

Comment: Number don't have bases. It is their string representation which has a base.

Comment: its the number system which has a base. that's what he mean.

Answer (score 2):

An integer value itself (e.g. an `int`) doesn't *have* a base, really. It's just a number.

Bases are mostly important for *textual* representations. (They're also important in floating point numbers as that determines what sort of point is floating, but let's leave that aside for the moment.) So it would make sense to have:

```
public static String convertToDecimal(String input, int base)
```

Or even:

```
public static int convertFromBase(String input, int base)
```

But your current signature doesn't make much sense. 1023 is *not* the same as "1023"... it's just a number.

Fortunately, Java has the second of these signatures built in, as [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), so you don't need to do it yourself. If you *do* want to do it yourself, I would write it something like:

```
public static int convertFromBase(String input, int base) {
    int multiplier = 1;
    int result = 0;
    for (int index = input.length() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        // This will handle hex for you. TODO: Validation!
        int digitValue = Character.digit(input.charAt(index), base);
        result += digitValue * multiplier;
        multiplier *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method Integer.parseInt(String,int) does exactly what your are looking for.

```
Integer.parseInt("1023",4) //returns 75
```